# Can't read file even though permissions are correct

Tags: linux, permissions, bash, file-permissions

I have a dir with read permissions for ssl-cert:

```
root@yellowstone:~/certs# ls -lah
total 28K
drwxr-x--- 2 root ssl-cert 4.0K Oct 23 16:58 .
drwx------ 7 root root     4.0K Oct 23 17:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root ssl-cert 2.0K Oct 23 16:58 certificate1.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root ssl-cert 2.0K Oct 23 16:58 certificate2.crt
-rw-r--r-- 1 root ssl-cert 2.0K Oct 23 16:58 certificate3.crt
-rw-r----- 1 root ssl-cert 3.2K Oct 23 16:58 privatekey.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root ssl-cert 2.0K Oct 23 16:58 certificate4.crt
```

I have an user in the group ssl-cert:

```
root@yellowstone:~/certs# id prosody 
uid=116(prosody) gid=124(prosody) groups=124(prosody),115(ssl-cert)
```

But if I try to access either the dir or a file in it I get "Permission denied":

```
prosody@yellowstone:/$ cd /root/certs
bash: cd: /root/certs: Permission denied
prosody@yellowstone:/$ cat /root/certs/certificate4.crt
cat: /root/certs/certificate4.crt: Permission denied
prosody@yellowstone:/$ cat /root/certs/privatekey.key
cat: /root/certs/privatekey.key: Permission denied
```

What do I have to change to access the files as user `prosody`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to put the files in some other directory, *not* under `/root`. Such files are intended to be accessed *only* by the system administrator, and it's a very bad idea to allow any other user to get in there.

As you can clearly see from your directory listing, the permissions on `/root` allow only root to read and write that directory. All others have no permissions at all. This is why user prosody cannot traverse that directory.

> ```
> drwx------ 7 root root     4.0K Oct 23 17:20 ..
> ```

Comment: OK, thanks, putting in in another directory fixed it.

Comment: But why can't I `cat` the file? Why do I need permissions to traverse all parent directorys for that?

Comment: Yes, the effective UID/GID needs sufficient permissions on the **whole path**, not just the file.

Comment: To read a file on POSIX compatible system (e.g. Linux or MacOS) one needs to have execute (`x`) bit set on every directory in the full path of the file and read bit (`r`) set in the file at the end of the path. The `x` in directory doesn't mean that you can somehow execute the directory as a program but it allows travelsing through the directory in the path. The read bit (`r`) in directory means "can this user list contents of the directory?"

Answer (score -3):

Just give prosody permission to enter in directory , execute permission

```
chmod 701 /root
```